# Как в методе класса обозначить пересекаются ли круги или нет(Питон)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы, методы

Есть код

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center  
        self.radius = radius  
    def square(self):
        return (3.14 * self.radius**2)
```

Он принимает координаты центра круга и его радиус, а потом находит площадь круга, его необходимо доработать, добавив ему ещё один метод `def do_intersect`, который будет принимать другой объект класса Circle и возвращать True или False в зависимости от того, пересекаются круги или нет. Но как это сделать я не знаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

понятно что две окружности пересекаются, если расстояние между их центрами меньше суммы их радиусов.
Поэтому ищем гипотенузу и сравниваем.
Наверно координаты идут кортежем, поэтому вынесем их в конец инициализации

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius, *args):
        self.center = args
        self.radius = radius

    def square(self):
        return 3.14 * self.radius ** 2

    def do_intersect(self, other):
        dist = ((self.center[0] - other.center[0]) ** 2 + (self.center[1] - other.center[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
        return abs(self.radius - other.radius) <= dist <= self.radius + other.radius

circle = Circle(3, 1, 1)
circle2 = Circle(1, 1, 1)
print(circle.do_intersect(circle2))
```

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь вопросы?

Comment: Случай когда одна окружность целиком внутри другой будет выдан за их пересечение. Например, если их центры совпадают, а радиусы различаются.

Comment: Добавил это условие

Answer (score 1):

проверить пересекаются ли круги можно взяв расстояние их центров и вычесть сумму их радиусов

```
def f(center1, r1, center2, r2):
    x = center1[0] - center2[0]
    y = center1[1] - center2[1]
    
    dist = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5
    
    if dist < abs(r1 - r2):
        return False
    dist -= r1 + r2
    
    return dist < 0
```

Comment: Ваш код выдает неправильный результат для `center1, r1 = [0, 0], 3 ; center2, r2 = [1, 1], 1`

Comment: да..а ещё ```def do_intersect``` по условию должен принимать другой объект класса Circle, то есть я правильно понимаю что def должен выглядеть как ```def do intersect(self, other_Circle)```?